# PHP While Loop: Second While Loop not showing data

Tags: php, while-loop

I'm having trouble on While Loop. Here is my code:

```
<?php
//DISPLAY'S SKILL LIST
$showItemList = $con->query('SELECT * FROM items');


if ($showItemList->num_rows > 0) {
     $x=1;
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $showItemList->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo '<tr>';
         echo '<td>' . $x++ . '</td>';
         echo '<td>' . $row['item_id'] . '</td>';
         echo '<td>' . $row['item_name'] . '</td>';
         echo '<td>' . $row['item_category'] . '</td>';
         echo '<td>' . $row['item_costprice'] . '</td>';
         echo '<td>' . $row['item_retailprice'] . '</td>';
         echo '<td>' . $row['item_tax'] . '%</td>';
         echo '<td>';
              $showInHouseQty = $con->query('SELECT SUM(item_quantity) AS TotalQuantityInStock FROM item_inventory_inhouse WHERE item_id="'.$row['item_id'].'"');
              while($row = $showInHouseQty->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo $row['TotalQuantityInStock'];
              } 
         echo '</td>';
         echo '<td>'; 
                $showPharmaQty = $con->query('SELECT SUM(item_quantity) AS TotalPharmaQty FROM item_inventory_inpharmacy WHERE item_id="'.$row['item_id'].'"');
              while($row = $showPharmaQty->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo $row['TotalPharmaQty'];
              }
         echo '</td>';                                                                                                                     
         echo '</tr>';
     }     
} 


?>
```

Well, the problem is, I can't get the result of `$row['TotalPharmaQty'];`

Comment: Does the second query work?

Comment: your overwriting `$row` twice, change that value

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you use the same variables in nested while loops as are in the parent while loop, they will overwrite. Change `$row` in the second and third while loops to `$row2` and `$row3` respectively, and it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks! I highly appreciate your answer. Solved my problem.